# Unable to install imbalanced-learn

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to install the `imbalanced-learn` package in Python3 with the following command: `pip install - U imbalanced-learn`. I get this error:

> ```
>      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement imbalanced-learn (from versions: )
> No matching distribution found for imbalanced-learn
> You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
> You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
> ```

However, when I try upgrading using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` I get this:

> ```
> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (10.0.1)
> You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
> You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
> ```

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: did you try with conda? maybe it will work for you `conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn`

Comment: I tried this and and got this error: `CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>`. I'm connected to the internet so not sure what the problem is.

Comment: my other try would be to use github + pip installation then, but i guess it also won't work

Answer (score 1):

I had also struggled with installing it but it worked for me with:

```
conda install imbalanced-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying doing a pip install in your conda environment with `pip install imbalanced-learn`. If that doesn't work then I'll recommend you revert back to v0.3 with `conda install -c glemaitre imbalanced-learn`